# Fundamental limitations of cell arrays, arrays of structs, and scalar structs?

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

I've been using Matlab on and off for decades.  I thought I had a good grip on arrays, structs, cell arrays, tables, an array of structs, and a struct in which each field is an array.  For the latter two, I assumed that each field needed to be of uniform type.  I'm finding that no such limitation exists:

[image]

Perhaps Matlab is becoming more flexible with the years (I'm using 2015b), but it does undermine my confidence in choosing the best type of variable for a task if I find that understanding of the limitations of each type is wrong.  For the purpose of this question, I can't really articulate the needs of the task because the manner in which I break down a large to-do into tasks depends on my understanding of the data types at my disposal, and their advantages/limitations.

I can (and have) read online documentation ad nauseum, and while they will walk you through code to illustrate what the data types are able to do, I haven't yet come across a succinct description of the comparative limitations between cell arrays, arrays of structs, and structs whose fields are themselves arrays -- to the point that I can use that knowledge to choose the best structure in a given situation.  Basic stuff, I do find, e.g., the same field names will occur in each struct of a struct array (but as the above example shows, each field of each struct can contain highly heterogeneous data types and/or array sizes).

**THE QUESTION**

Can anyone point to such a comparison of limitations between cell arrays, arrays of structs, and scalar structs whose fields are themselves arrays?  I'm looking for a treatment at a level that informs a coder in deciding on the best trade-off between (i) speed, (ii) memory, and (iii) readability, maintainability, and evolvability.

I've deliberately left out tables because, although I'm enamoured of their convenient access to, and subsetting of, data sets (and presentation thereof), they have proved rather slow for manipulation of data.  They have their uses, and I use them liberally, but I'm not interested in them for the purpose of this comparison, which is under-the-hood algorithm coding.

Comment: Can you narrow your question down? And yes the same field of different elements of a `struct` array don't have to be of the same type. Between `cell` and `array`, it is mainly whatever makes access convenient. Neither enjoys (or needs to) the kind of optimization that `array` comes with. `dict` is good for accessing key-value pairs conveniently. Be careful that equality of a field of a `struct` is by reference. I haven't investigated it for `cell` but I would assume the same.

Comment: As for `table`, I am not sure if it is as optimized as `array` for matrix manipulation. I don't have access to it. But I have seen in the documentations that `table` allows you more options to output to file and interface with other utilities.

Comment: "For the latter two, I assumed that each field needed to be of uniform type. I'm finding that no such limitation exists." This limitation never existed.

Comment: @Argyll: Is `dict` an Octave thing? MATLAB has none, at least not in the core language. It could be a custom class in one of the toolboxes. MATLAB does have `containers.Map`, which is a hash table. || Also, what do you mean by "equality of a field of a `struct` is by reference"?

Comment: @Argyll: Thanks for the prompt to clariy the question.  I've revised accordingly.  I'm not sure what you mean when you say that equality between structs is by reference (I'm familiar with the concept of reference vs. value).  I acknowledge that none of these data types are as lean as raw arrays of basic data types.  Regarding dict, I use document.map for hash tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your question eventually narrows down to these three "types" of data structures:

> comparative limitations between cell arrays, arrays of structs, and structs whose fiels are themselves arrays

[Note that "structs whose fields are themselves arrays" I translate as "scalar structs" here. An array of structs can also contain arbitrary arrays. My thinking becomes clear below, I hope.]

To me, these are not very different. All three are containers for heterogeneous data. (Heterogeneous data is non-uniform data, each data element is potentially of a different type and size.) Each of these statements can return an array of any type, unrelated to the type of any other array in the container:

- cell array: `array{i,j}`
- struct array: `array(i,j).value`
- scalar struct: `array.value`

So it all depends on how you want to index:

```
array(i,j).value
       ^     ^
       A     B
```

If you want to index using `A` only, use a cell array (though you then need curly braces, of course). If you want to index using `B` only, use a scalar struct. If you want both `A` and `B`, use a struct array.

There is no difference in cost that I'm aware of. Each of the arrays contained in these containers takes up some space. The spatial overhead of the various containers is similar, and I have never noted a time overhead difference.

However, there is a huge difference between these two:

```
array(i).value   % s1
array.value(i)   % s2
```

I think that the question deals with this difference also. `s1` has a lot more spatial overhead than `s2`:

```
>> s1=struct('value',num2cell(1:100))
s1 = 
  1×100 struct array with fields:
    value
>> s2=struct('value',1:100)
s2 = 
  struct with fields:
    value: [1×100 double]
>> whos
  Name      Size             Bytes  Class     Attributes
  s1        1x100            12064  struct              
  s2        1x1                976  struct
```

The data needs 800 bytes, so `s2` has 176 bytes of overhead, whereas `s1` has 11264 (1408%)!

The reason is not the *container*, but the fact that we're storing one array with 100 elements in one, and 100 arrays with one element in the other. Each array has a header of a certain size that MATLAB uses to know what type of array it is, what sizes it has, to manage its storage and the delayed copy mechanism. The fewer arrays one has, the less memory one uses.

So, **don't use a heterogeneous container to store scalars!** These things only make sense when you need to store larger arrays, or arrays of different type or size.

---

The heterogeneous container that is not explicitly asked about (and after the edit explicitly *not* asked about) is the table. A table is similar to a scalar struct in that each column of the table is a single array, and different columns can have different types. Note that it is possible to use a cell array as a column, allowing for heterogenous elements to be stored in a column, but they make most sense if this is not the case.

One difference with a scalar struct is that each column must have the same number of rows. Another difference is that indexing can look like that of a cell array, a scalar struct, or a struct array.

Thus, the table forces some constrains upon the contained data, which is very beneficial in some circumstances.

However, and as the OP noted, working with tables is slower than working with structs. This is because `table` is a custom class, not a native type like structs and cell arrays. If you type `edit table` in MATLAB, you'll see the source code, how it's implemented. It's a `classdef` file, just like something any of us could write. Consequently, it has the same speed limitations: the JIT is not optimized for it, indexing into a table implies running a function written as an M-file, etc.

---

One more thing: Don't create cell arrays of structs, or scalar structs with cell arrays. This increases the levels of containers, which increases overhead (both in space and time), and makes the contents more difficult to use. I have seen questions here on SO related to difficulty accessing data, caused by this type of construct:

```
data{i,j}.value   % A cell array with structs. Don't do this!
data.value{i,j}   % A struct with cell arrays. Don't do this!
```

The first example is equal to a struct array (with a lot more overhead), except there is no control over the struct fields within each cell. That is, it is possible for one of the cells to not have a `.value` field.

The second example makes sense only if `value` is a different size than a second struct field. If all struct fields are (supposed to be) cell arrays of the same size like this, then use a struct array. Again, less overhead and more uniformity.

Comment: You interpretted my question correctly.  I've revised the original "post" accordingly.  Your term "scalar structs" is a good description for my mental picture, since the struct itself is not arrayed -- the arraying is pushed down to the level of the individual fields.  I knew that your `s1` exacts a cost in terms of speed, so I'm not surprised that it exacts a cost in terms of memory, presumably due to more elaborate internal data organization.  I use it sparingly, when it improves readability due to better alignment with how I think about the problem data.

Comment: In your code, I was surprised that `s1=struct('value',num2cell(1:100))` does not behave the same as `s1.value=num2cell(1:100)`, but sure enough, it's one of the exceptional behaviours that are captured in the documentation.  I find Matlab has a lot of such notational rules to remember, a result of its long evolution.

Comment: I wasn't entirely sure what you mean by "heterogeneous container", but I'm guessing that this refers to arrays whose elemental types don't have to be uniform, e.g., struct arrays, cell arrays.  To be clear, the elements *are* superficially "uniform" in the sense that they are structs or cells, but the member variables don't have to contain the same data type across the array in the case of struct arrays; in the case of cell arrays, the contents don't have to be even remotely similar at all.

Comment: Odd.  The above 3 comments are directed at `Cris Luengo`.  For some reason, stackoverflow removes the leading `@Cris Luengo: ` from my comments, even if I go back and add them back in.

Comment: @user36800: The author of a post is always notified about comments to that post, possibly the @-tag is removed because it's not necessary. I have edited the post a little bit, hopefully making a few things more explicit and also addressing your execution time concerns.

Comment: @user36800: Concerning the `num2cell` bit: this is how the `struct` function works. `struct('key',{values},'key2',{values},...)` creates a struct array with the same size as the cell arrays (they should all be the same size or scalars). Knowing how to quickly build a struct array like that in one line as an example is one of those things you pick up along the way... Yes, MATLAB has a huge number of functions, even discounting all the toolboxes, and this number grows every year. I discover new ones, or new ways to use them, almost daily.

Comment: @user36800: A last comment, regarding your statement " the elements are superficially "uniform" in the sense that they are structs or cells..." I think of these things as part of the container. The container is what you index into, the contents is what you get out when you index. These three "container types" are indexed differently, field names are part of that indexing. What they contain are arrays of arbitrary types. All of these containers can contain completely arbitrary and non-uniform types, there is no necessary or implied similarity.