# Do MATLAB tables remove the need for dictionaries?

Tags: matlab, dictionary, matlab-table

MATLAB `table`s let you index into any column/field using the row name, e.g., `MyTable.FourthColumn('SecondRowName')`.  Compared to this, dictionaries (`containers.Map`) seem primitive, e.g., it serves the role of a 1-column table.  It also has its own dedicated syntax, which slows down the thinking about how to code.

I'm beginning to think that I can forget the use of dictionaries.  Are there typical situations for which that would not be advisable?

Comment: In the mean time, here are related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34767016/7328782 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/49826177/7328782

Comment: Thanks for the links, Cris.  I am indeed referring to Containers.Map.  The comparison with struct is indeed relevant, although they refer to using the struct field name as the key whereas I am referring to the table row name as the key.  Admittedly, I can also use the table field name as the key, but they are subject to more restrictions. *If* I confine the scope of the question to cases in which the key consists only of string, then in comparison with Containers.Map, it seems that a table offers much more flexibility in all other respects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** No. `containers.Map` has uses that cannot be replaced with a `table`. And I would not choose a `table` for a dictionary.

---

`containers.Map` and `table` have many differences worth noting. They each have their use. A third container we can use to create a dictionary is a `struct`.

To use a `table` as a dictionary, you'd define only one column, and specify row names:

```
T = table(data,'VariableNames',{'value'},'RowNames',names);
```

Here are some notable differences between these containers when used as a dictionary:

- Speed: The `struct` has the fastest access by far (10x). `containers.Map` is about twice as fast as a `table` when used in an equivalent way (i.e. a single-column table with row names).
- Keys: A `struct` is limited to keys that are valid variable names, the other two can use any string as a key. The `containers.Map` keys can be scalar numbers as well (floating-point or integer).
- Data: They all can contain heterogeneous data (each value has a different type), but a `table` changes how you index if you do this (`T.value(name)` for homogeneous data, `T.value{name}` for heterogeneous data).
- Syntax: To lookup the key, `containers.Map` provides the most straight-forward syntax: `M(name)`. A `table` turned into a dictionary requires the pointless use of the column name: `T.value(name)`. A `struct`, if the key is given by the contents of a variable, looks a little awkward: `S.(name)`.
- Construction: (See the code below.) `containers.Map` has the most straight-forward method for building a dictionary from given data. The `struct` is not meant for this purpose, and therefore it gets complicated.
- Memory: This is hard to compare, as `containers.Map` is implemented in Java and therefore `whos` reports only 8 bytes (i.e. a pointer). A `table` *can* be more memory efficient than a `struct`, if the data is homogeneous (all values have the same type) and scalar, as in this case all values for one column are stored in a single array.
- Other differences:

  - A `table` obviously can contain multiple columns, and has lots of interesting methods to manipulate data.
  - A `stuct` is actually a struct array, and can be indexed as `S(i,j).(name)`. Of course `name` can be fixed, rather than a variable, leading to `S(i,j).name`. Of the three, this is the only built-in type, which is the reason it is so much more efficient.

Here is some code that shows the difference between these three containers for constructing a dictionary and looking up a value:

```
% Create names
names = cell(1,100);
for ii=1:numel(names)
   names{ii} = char(randi(+'az',1,20));
end
name = names{1};

% Create data
values = rand(1,numel(names));

% Construct
M = containers.Map(names,values);

T = table(values.','VariableNames',{'value'},'RowNames',names);

S = num2cell(values);
S = [names;S];
S = struct(S{:});

% Lookup    
M(name)
T.value(name)
S.(name)

% Timing lookup
timeit(@()M(name))
timeit(@()T.value(name))
timeit(@()S.(name))
```

Timing results (microseconds):

```
M: 16.672
T: 23.393
S:  2.609
```

Comment: All true. In some cases, the readability advantage of setting up a lookup
table of literals favours tables, if that is important to the context:
`Literals = {
    'RowName' 'NumDat';
    'dog'     9       ;
    'cat'     12      ;
    'mouse'   pi      ;
    'horse'   exp(1)  ;
};
T = cell2table( Literals(2:end,:), 'VariableNames',Literals(1,:) );
T.Properties.RowNames = T.RowName`.  I would have each statement and cell row in a separate line so that the tabular nature and key/value associations are instantly seen.

Comment: Along the lines of your point about interesting ways to manipulate table data, you can look up a series of keys at once, e.g., `T.NumDat({'mouse' 'dog'})`.
If you have multiple string columns, you can also swap them in as RowNames
for use as keys.

Comment: @user2153235: With `Literals` you can also easily build a struct and a `Map`: `struct(Literals{:})` (actually needs a transpose first), and `containers.Map(Literals(1,:),Literals(2,:))`. In both cases the first row of `Literals` is not needed.

Comment: @user2153235: If this type of manipulation is needed, then indeed, use a `table`.

Comment: That conversion of cell array to struct is cool. Something to keep in mind if I need the speed advantage, and I'm doing scalar lookups of a single value.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can go simpler, you can access structs using string field:

```
clear
% define
mydata.('vec')=[2 4 1]; 
mydata.num=12.58;
% get 
select1='num'; 
value1=mydata.(select1); %method 1 
select2='vec'; 
value2=getfield(mydata,select2) %method 2
```

Comment: True that!  Do you have a code pattern that builds up the lookup table in one statement, e.g., like [`cell2table`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2table.html?searchHighlight=cell2table&s_tid=doc_srchtitle#btzdqfx-3)?  I'm thinking about how to keep code streamlined.  As well, what motivated me to post the question was wondering whether there was anything that dictionaries have to offer which might cause one not to dispense with them entirely.  Thanks.

Comment: @user2153235 You can use `cell2struct`... These are all different constructs with their own uses though.

Comment: I should have clarified that the link points to how converting from cells as the initializing data allows for the input data to be very well laid out so that the associations are immediately obvious.  I provide an example in my comment to Cris Luengo's answer, along with mention of advantages in vectorized table lookups and convenient swapping of keys. I must be in a phase of puppy love with tables.